# Проверка файлов .txt с помощью getimagesize()

Tags: php, mime, проверка

Проверяю загружаемые пользователями thumb картинки с помощью `getimagesize()` 
Вот таким образом:

```php
$imageinfo = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
  if($imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/gif' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/jpeg' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/png') {
    $data['error'] = 'Ошибка загрузки. Допустимые форматы: .jpeg .gif .png';
    echo json_encode( $data );
    exit;
  } else {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
    if ($width < $minWidth || $height < $minHeight || $height > $maxHeight || $width > $maxWidth){
      $data['error'] = 'Изображение не может быть меньше '.$minWidth.' и больше '.$maxWidth.' пикселей <br>
      по одной из сторон. Пожалуйста выберите другое фото.';
      echo json_encode( $data );
      exit;
    }
  }
```

То есть проверка на mime типы. Всё работает превосходно с разными форматами, но при загрузке пользователями файла .txt вместо изображений сервер выдает `500 (Internal Server Error)` со словами 
`LOG.error: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'getimagesize(): Read error!`

Пытался сделать так:

```php
try {getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);}
    catch (Exception $e) {
    }
    if ($e === FALSE) {
//ERROR
    }
```

Не помогло.
Как нужно сделать, что бы при ошибке выполнения getimagesize() была не 500 ошибка, а ответ в виде `echo json_encode( $error );` ?

Comment: И, может знающие люди подскажут... Что такого особенного в формате .txt?? Просто getimagesize() "неправильно" себя ведет только с txt файлами!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [оператор `@`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) :

```
if ($imageinfo  = @getimagesize($file['tmp_name'])) {
    //...ваш код
} else {
    //выводим json с ошибкой
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, как сам не догадался! Но есть проблема. Я использую шаблонизатор Blade и фрейм laravel. Надеюсь конфликтов с операторами не будет... попробую отпишусь!

Comment: Конфликтов с blade - нету! Всё работает отлично, Спасибо!